# Run custom command with webpack watch for Universal App

Tags: javascript, webpack, isomorphic-javascript

I'm working in a universal web app that uses webpack as build system. I have directory structure like:

```
|-server/
|-- index.js   # Server Side Rendering
|-client/
|-- index.js   # Client Side Rendering 
|-common
|-- SomeReactComponent.js #Imports things like .css files
```

I have a `webpack.config.js` like:

```
export default [{
  //config for server
  target: 'node'
},
{
  //config for client
  target: 'web'
}];
```

In dev, I want to run `webpack` in `watch mode`.

My Scripts:

```
webpack --watch & node ./build/server
```

The problem here is:

- node start before build is done
- how to restart node every time that webpack rebuild?

If there was a way to tell webpack a command to exec  post-build. (?)

Maybe I'm missing something. I admit I'm really newbie in javascript. I know build system is one of the main challenge of Universal Apps.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a hot-reloader like https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon to restart node whenever a change is made to your js files.

Comment: Thank you for response. Do you know how to start nodemon right after webpack finishing build?

Comment: Nodemon will auto restart once webpack finishes, so it is a non-issue.

Comment: Yeah. You're right. The only issue is the first nodemon call. If you look closely the previous example in my start script, I run webpack --watch in backgroud and run the server. Due webpack still no finishes it fails staring the server.